# Compare hazard ratios in case-control setup

Tags: cox-model, case-control-study

quick disclaimer: first time poster; i have searched through the forums extensively but please bear with me if this is a silly question or point me towards the solution if it has been answered before.

anyways, I have received two datasets:
A contains a number of cases, i.e. affected by a disease. 
B contains 4 times as many controls. they are similar in age and sex. outcome and covariates are identically recorded in the two datasets.

i have then constructed two separate cox-ph models with the same dichotomized covariate and it appears that this covariate is protective, i.e. HR 0.8, in the one group and a borderline-harmful, i.e. HR ~1.02, in the other. both results have very narrow 95% CIs and are (highly) significant owing to the large sample size in both groups.

is there a valid way to compare these HRs and obtain a p-value for such testing? I have seen simple comparisons with x² in (high ranking) journals, but surely that can't be appropriate.

thank you!

Comment: Need to combine two models into one model. For tow models, basically there is no way to comparing the contents between two models unless the two models have nested relation.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site.

One simple way to proceed would be to combine the two datasets into a single dataset that annotates whether each case came from group A or group B. Then you could include your covariate of interest, the group membership, and the *interaction* between group membership and that covariate as predictors in a multiple-regression Cox model. A significant interaction term would document that the covariate has different implications for outcome depending on whether a case is in group A or group B.

Two warnings. First, you say that your covariate is "dichotomized." If this is truly a two-valued covariate that's fine, but if you have taken a numeric covariate and broken it into two classes based on some cutoff you could be getting into trouble. You would probably be better off modeling with the numeric value directly (perhaps after some transformation). See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/117972/28500) for one discussion of this issue on this site. Second, although this is a case-control design, you might still want to incorporate the other clinical covariates into the Cox model as case matching doesn't always work as well as one might hope.

Comment: thank you! - also to the user above. please note that the covariate of interest is indeed 0/1 (its another exposure yes/no).

When calculating in the merged data, I get roughly the same HR for the covariate as in the control group, a high HR for the "disease" group of course and a highly significant interaction between the covariate:disease-group. The HR for this interaction is <1 - is it now sound to conclude that belonging to the disease group is indeed protective? Thanks again.

Comment: @raphael I would be careful about calling disease-group membership "protective," which could be interpreted to mean that those in the disease group with the covariate have better survival than those in the matched control group who have the covariate: that would depend on the additional survival benefit of control/disease group membership. You can say that, for those in the disease group, those with the covariate have better survival, while the covariate has limited relation to survival for the disease-free. Also, "protective" can have causal implications that survival analysis can't prove.